# Invariant subspace of a representation of a Lie algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

This may be silly. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be an Lie algebra, with $V$ a nonzero representation.
Denote the invariant subspace $V^{\mathfrak{g}}=\{v\in V|x.v=0,\forall x\in \mathfrak{g}\}$.

Question:Is $V^{\mathfrak{g}}$ a subrepresentation of $V$? It seems to satisfy all axioms to become a subrepresentation. But I just wonder why the textbook is vague about it (namely, Lorentz's book) and calling it a subspace.

Comment: The textbook says that it is a subspace, which is true. But it is also invariant, yes. Did you check any another book so far?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, I checked Hall's Book(GTM 222), which also just mentions it as a subspace. I asked my professor about it, he/she was also vague about it, say that $V^{\mathfrak{g}}$ already "use up" all the $\mathfrak{g}$ actions, which makes me confused. That's why I ask here. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Anything that satisfies the axioms of X is an X. But we don't write out all the things something is every time we talk about it.

Comment: It is a subrepresentation but not interesting in the sense that $ \mathfrak{g} $ acts trivially on $ V^{\mathfrak{g}} $ and this is what your professor perhaps meant to say - "$ V^{\mathfrak{g}} $ uses up all the $ \mathfrak{g} $-actions". So it is as good as being a subspace only.